# Hangfire Jobs are running old version of code?

Tags: hangfire, cron-task

My hangfire seems to run old versions of my code.
the logs say:

```
fail: Hangfire.AutomaticRetryAttribute[0]
      Failed to process the job '14549': an exception occurred.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Aftermarket.Server.Common.PqatExport.PQATRepository' while attempting to activate 'Aftermarket.Server.Common.PqatExport.PQATExportHandler'.
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
         at Hangfire.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)
         at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__0()
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__2()
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext context, IEnumerable`1 filters)
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
         at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)
warn: Hangfire.AutomaticRetryAttribute[0]
      Failed to process the job '14553': an exception occurred. Retry attempt 8 of 10 will be performed in 00:43:52.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Aftermarket.Server.Common.PQAT_Export.HwsPQATExport.HwsPQATRepository' while attempting to activate 'Aftermarket.Server.Common.PQAT_Export.HwsPQATExport.HwsPQATExportHandler'.
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
         at Hangfire.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)
         at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__0()
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__2()
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext context, IEnumerable`1 filters)
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
         at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)
warn: Hangfire.AutomaticRetryAttribute[0]
      Failed to process the job '14555': an exception occurred. Retry attempt 3 of 10 will be performed in 00:00:52.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Aftermarket.Server.Common.PqatExport.PQATRepository' while attempting to activate 'Aftermarket.Server.Common.PqatExport.PQATExportHandler'.
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
         at Hangfire.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)
         at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__0()
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__2()
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext context, IEnumerable`1 filters)
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
         at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)
warn: Hangfire.AutomaticRetryAttribute[0]
      Failed to process the job '14555': an exception occurred. Retry attempt 5 of 10 will be performed in 00:05:31.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Aftermarket.Server.Common.PqatExport.PQATRepository' while attempting to activate 'Aftermarket.Server.Common.PqatExport.PQATExportHandler'.
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
         at Hangfire.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)
         at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__0()
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__2()
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext context, IEnumerable`1 filters)
         at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
         at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)
```

But i long ago removed Everything that has to do with the PQATExport from the startup.cs class ??
Its like Hangfire is trying to run old code that's deleted? How do I fix this?

Comment: Seems like, long ago, you scheduled a recurring job addressing PQATExport,
and this job is still referenced in the Hangfire Database.
You need to remove it.

Comment: This was the case! Thank you!